# Hibernate Data Truncation, Date-Time Field

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

Using Hibernate (with MySQL), saving an entity with a date-time outside of the supported range (after the year 9999). I get the following exception:

`Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'column_name' at row 1`

The dates are encoded as an `java.time.Instant`.

1. Though it is normal that the insertion fails, why does Hibernate *attempt* to insert it (is that a bug?)
2. Aside from a manual check, are there any input validations that I can add (annotation?)

Stack trace:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'column_name' at row 1
   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:104)
   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:637)
   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:418)
   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092)
   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040)

   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is sent by your Mysql server not hibernate

If you try running the sql script bellow on your local you obtain the same error
While BIRTHDAY has a date time type

```
INSERT INTO test.TestTable
(Name, BIRTHDAY)
VALUES('Test', '');
```

Here your date time value is empty.

Comment: Hi Abdelijalil, thank you for your response. I know that the error is sent by the MySQL server, but I don't understand why Hibernate is sending the empty string, instead of throwing an exception before sending the empty string. I am worried that without stricter validation, other errors are waiting to happen at runtime.